# 3 Mysql Inner Joins with last join being the ORDER BY Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables I'm trying to inner join (ambitious I know). The first query of the join, just basically queries my members table to pipe into the second query, which is the post table that actually holds the posts for those members (users search by member info to see their posts). The third and final query is simply ordering by the frequency of the most viewed posts. I have these two queries working separately:

```
$sql_string = "
SELECT m.id
     , m.username
     , m.gender
     , p.* 
  FROM members m
  JOIN posts p
    ON p.member_id = m.id  
 WHERE m.active='y' 
   AND m.gender='M' 
   AND m.city='Los Angeles' 
   AND m.state='California' 
   AND p.active='y';
";
```

which accomplishes the first 2 queries and this final query:

```
$sql_string2 = "SELECT post_id FROM post_views GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC";
```

Which accomplishes the final query. I just need to combine the 2, but when I do that:

```
$final_sql_string = "SELECT members.id, members.username, members.gender, posts.* FROM members INNER JOIN posts ON members.id = posts.member_id WHERE members.active='y' AND members.gender='M' AND members.city='Los Angeles' AND members.state='California' AND posts.active='y' INNER JOIN post_views ON posts.id = post_views.post_id GROUP BY post_views.post_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC";
```

I get an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN post_views ON posts.id = post_views.post_id GROUP BY post_views.post_' at line 1
```

Any ideas? Here are my tables for anyone interested:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `age` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `gender` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `active` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
 `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `title` text NOT NULL,
 `comments` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
 `post_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `list_weight` double NOT NULL,
 `active` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=47 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_views` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `post_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=287 ;
```

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, it looks like it should work, but I have no idea why it's not.?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Well the syntax is obviously wrong -but I'm not sure that fixing that really gets to the heart of the problem.

Comment: What's so obviously wrong about it? that's exactly why I made this post. Please enlighten me.

Comment: WHERE comes after JOIN

Comment: @Strawberry Oh Ok. Btw, for anyone seeing this, that first query was not my original query. It was modified (likely by a moderator) to more than likely be more legible for the viewer. My initial query was: $sql_string = "SELECT members.id, members.username, members.gender, posts.* FROM members INNER JOIN posts ON members.id = posts.member_id WHERE members.active='y' AND members.gender='M' AND members.city='Los Angeles' AND members.state='California' AND posts.active='y'". Just wanted to note that so anyone won't get confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT m.id
     , m.username
     , m.gender
     , p.* 
     , pc.post_count
  FROM members m
  JOIN posts p
    ON p.member_id = m.id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) post_count FROM post_views GROUP BY post_id
    ) pc ON p.id = pc.post_id 
 WHERE m.active='y' 
   AND m.gender='M' 
   AND m.city='Los Angeles' 
   AND m.state='California' 
   AND p.active='y'
 ORDER BY post_count DESC;
```

"join in" the counts you gathered and order by those.

If you want to keep your "style" you may use:

```
SELECT m.id
     , m.username
     , m.gender
     , p.* 
  FROM members m
  JOIN posts p
    ON p.member_id = m.id
 WHERE m.active='y' 
   AND m.gender='M' 
   AND m.city='Los Angeles' 
   AND m.state='California' 
   AND p.active='y'
 ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_views WHERE post_id = p.id) DESC;
```

Comment: I know this is the way you would probably write this query, but is there a way to write this query in my same style? This query is beig generated dynamically and I would rather not have to reconfigure a ton of code just to get this one thing sorted out. Particularly, How should I rewrite this part of my query: "INNER JOIN post_views ON posts.id = post_views.post_id GROUP BY post_views.post_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC"? That seems to be my problem. If you put the answer in these comments and it works, I'll go ahead and accept your answer.

Comment: See my edit above, but I am more or less sure that this will be a lot slower.

Comment: Just a sidenote: You cannot JOIN inside your normal query after you specified a where clause. So the second variant is the closest you can get with valid syntax...

Comment: You are a true SQL ninja. One last question. Why is querying the database my way slower than doing it your way?

Comment: It depends on the MySQL version you use and the optimizations which are applied, but your variant is a "dependent subquery". Those were feared as very slow in mysql version ≤ 5.1. There were made some serious improvements in the last versions, so this query might be fast (or faster) now. Just try both variants, let MySQL [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) them to you and see which one performs good for you (if you have the choice at all...)